# How to obtain character at a specific place?

Tags: r

example:

```
"A.B.C.D"
"apple.good.sad.sea"
"X1.AN2.ED3.LK8"
```

What I need is to obtain the string specifically between the second dot and the third dot.

result:

```
"C"
"sad"
"ED3"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `base::strsplit`, loop thr the elements to get the 3rd one

```
v <- c("A.B.C.D", "apple.good.sad.sea", "X1.AN2.ED3.LK8")
sapply(strsplit(v, "\\."), `[[`, 3L)
```

output:

```
[1] "C"   "sad" "ED3"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `unlist(strsplit(str,split = "."))[3]` to get the third sub-string, where the original string is split by "." when you apply `strsplit`

Answer (score 2):

Using regex in `gsub`.

```
v <- c("A.B.C.D", "apple.good.sad.sea", "X1.AN2.ED3.LK8", "A.B.C.D.E")
gsub("(.*?\\.){2}(.*?)(\\..*)", "\\2", v)
# [1] "C"   "sad" "ED3" "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use

```
sub("^([^.]*\\.){2}([^.]*)\\..*", "\\2", x)
# [1] "C"   "sad" "ED3"
```